# Calling COM Interop API from a Background Thread?

Tags: c#, com, task-parallel-library

I instantiate a service class that contains a COM interop component that does terminal automation. I am using Task Library (TPL) from Microsoft. I want to make calls to the COM object from a TPL task (background thread) so my UI doesn't freezes while the COM object is working.

However when I call my first function from the background thread (which receives an IntPtr) an COM Exception is thrown detailing HRESULT: 0xC0000005.

I know this is an access violation exception and I think I'm not mashaling my object the right way.

How can I call methods from a COM object created in the main thread from a background thread?

```
public void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    var comWrapper = new COMWrapper(); // A simple wrapper for a COM object

    Task.Factory
        .StartNew(() => LoadStuff(comWrapper))
        .ContinueWith(() => {
            // Output results...
        });
}

int LoadStuff(COMWrapper w)
{
    return w.LoadStuffFromCOM();
}
```

Method that calls the COM object:

```
int LoadStuffFromCOM()
{
    string buffer;
    IntPtr pointer = Marshal.StringToHGlobalUni(buffer);

    return comObject.GetValue(pointer); // Exception here...
}
```

Comment: COM exception `0xC0000005` is `access denied`. This is a privilege error. Since you posted no code, it's pretty hard to figure out what might be causing it. "When I call my first function" isn't much to go on, I'm afraid. Can you edit your question to provide more detail?

Comment: I'm calling a function from the background thread. It receives an IntPtr that outputs some values from the COM. It works just fine if I run it on the main thread.

Comment: Sorry dude, is just that I can't provide much code since I am not allowed to do so.

Comment: Read what I commented up there. The real code is just a method calling a COM component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have COM / OLE  Interop objects running on background, but they must be compiled with correct Threading Model

In case of Delphi for MTA it should be compiled

```
initialization
  TTypedComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TSomeLogic, Class_SomeLogic,
    ciMultiInstance, tmFree);
end.
```

In case of STA by default it uses

```
initialization
  TTypedComObjectFactory.Create(ComServer, TSomeLogic, Class_SomeLogic,
    ciMultiInstance, tmApartment);
end.
```

It should be simmilar in C/C++ and other unmanaged languages

More information can be found here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx#scalenetchapt07 _topic11](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647812.aspx#scalenetchapt07%20%5ftopic11)

Answer (score 1):

Many legacy COM objects were made to run inside of a desktop application. That means they expected to run on the UI thread, with the Windows message pump as the only synchronizing method.

You're now trying to run that code in an environment it may never have "heard of". There's a good chance that you have violated the assumptions the author made when he wrote the code.

The code may work if you don't violate the assumptions, but if you do, then you're going to have a problem (or two, or two dozen).

Answer (score 0):

IF you are desperate you could spawn a whole separate process which executed the com code. Then you would *only* have to write the **ipc**